# Change configuration file in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core

I am trying to create a self-contained .NET Core Console Application.
In my application, I have added a configuration file appsettings.json .
The goal is now that I need to have the possibility to modify the configuration file while the application is running (and published)

I have found several guides but they all point to the direction where I need to include the following function:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Adds services required for using options.
        services.AddOptions();

        // Register the IConfiguration instance which MyOptions binds against.
        services.Configure<DBSetting>(Configuration);

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

But when I do this all the methodes of services are red. If I look u IserviceCollection the doc says that it has become obsolete.
I did add

```
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(@"C:\Users\Maarten\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CorporationBot\CorporationBotCore\appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange:true);                
        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

in my Program.cs which lets me fetch the data in my config file.
Now I need a way to change my config while the application is running.
Any up to date ways to do it?

Comment: What version of .NET Core? What dependencies do you have in your `.csproj` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsft configurations that are written into built-in providers are not persisted. So you may need to write a custom provider and implement save there. Following link provides more info about asp.net configuration and a sample custom EF provider.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration

As a side note, if the value tends to change at runtime.Database or some other place also can be a possible alternative.

Comment: The link you gave me has the same code that I am using and it doesn't work. It gives me errors on the methodes.
they don't change all the time. The server admin just needs to be able to change them when the application starts to change the database values in the config file

Comment: And according to the comments on that document it seems outdates for .NET Core 2.0

Comment: What is the error it gives to you? If it is not a web application u may not need to add configure services.

Comment: Yes .Comments say that it needs to be updated.But sample ef core provider should show you a directional light.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#basic-sample-of-entity-framework-custom-provider

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add or restore nuget packages related to [configuration feature](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration).

- add a dependency to [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/)
- add a dependency to [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/)
- run `dotnet restore`

And don't forget to add namespace: `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;`